# Отладка в браузере Chrome

Tags: javascript, html

Не получается запустить следуший код.

Есть ли какието проблемы в коде ? Буду рад любому совету..

На данный момент использую файлы в блокноте..SublimeText

Прикпепил images от дебагера... немогу понять что Это VM359:1 ?

При отладки выдаётся следущий код.. что это такое ?

```
(function (){const touchEvents=["ontouchstart","ontouchend","ontouchmove","ontouchcancel"];var recepients=[window.__proto__,document.__proto__];for(var i=0;i<touchEvents.length;++i){for(var j=0;j<recepients.length;++j){if(!(touchEvents[i]in recepients[j]))
Object.defineProperty(recepients[j],touchEvents[i],{value:null,writable:true,configurable:true,enumerable:true});}}})()
```

```js
  function registerController(){

  
   document.getElementById("reg_button").onsubmit = function(){

    console.log("In the register");

    var user = {

    username:document.getElementById("reg_user_name").value,
    firstname:document.getElementById("first_name").value,
    lastname:document.getElementById("last_name").value,
    userid:document.getElementById("user_id").value,
    password:document.getElementById("reg_password").value,
    email:document.getElementById("reg_email").value

    }

  console.log(user.username);
  console.log(user.userid);
  console.log(user.firstname);
  console.log(user.lastname);
  console.log(user.password);
  console.log(user.email);

  registerHandler(user);

   }
 }

function registerHandler(user){


  console.log(user.username);
  console.log(user.userid);
  console.log(user.firstname);
  console.log(user.lastname);
  console.log(user.password);
  console.log(user.email);

   var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

   xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){

    if(xhr.readyState!=4 && xhr.status!=200){
        return window.alert(xhr.responseText);
    }
   }

    xhr.open("POST","http://localhost:8080/CouponOnWeb/webappl/register",true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type','application/json;charset=utf-8');
    xhr.send(user);
}
```

```html
 <form id = "registrator" onsubmit = "registerController()">

  <label for = "reg_user_name">User name:</label>
  <input id = "reg_user_name" name = "reg_user_name" type = "text" placeholder = "user name">
  <br>
  <label for = "first_name">First name:</label>
  <input id = "first_name" name = "first_name" type = "text" placeholder = "first name">
  <br>
  <label for = "last_name">Last name:</label>
  <input id = "last_name" name = "last_name" type = "text" placeholder = "last name">
  <br>
  <label for = "user_id">Id number:</label>
  <input id = "user_id" name = "user_id" type = "number" placeholder = "id number">
  <br>
  <label for = "reg_password">Password:</label>
  <input id = "reg_password" name = "reg_password" type = "text" placeholder = "password">
  <br>
  <label for = "reg_email">Email:</label>
  <input id = "reg_email" name = "reg_email" type = "email" placeholder = "email">
  <br>
  <input id = "reg_button" name = "reg_button" type = "submit" value = "Register">
  </form>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en-US">

<head>
 
<meta charset="UTF-8"> 
<title>CouponSellingSystem</title>

<script src = "controllers.js"></script>
<script src = "navigator.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">

</head>
```

[image: Result of break point]

[image: the break point]

[Debugging](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f86mh.png)

[image: break point]

Comment: а в консоль выводятся данные, введенные Вами? Хороший способ ставить точки останова через **debugger**

Comment: В консоль не выводятся данные.. Из туториалов смотрел там у людей при отладки появляется локальная scope в которой данные о переменных.. У меня же Global.. 
CallStack анонимная функция VM336:1.. Есть второй лист(проект) со скриптами, там испольую window.onload но он загружет другие функции и все работает.. Это я так сказал малоли может както связанно с данной проблемой..

Comment: используйте не минифицированную версию скрипта, либо нажмите кнопку _форматировать_ ниже в этом окне

Comment: @Grundy - я понятие не имею что ты сказал.. Можно както по проше ? 
Я JS занимаюсь вторую неделю, паралельно к java..

Comment: Добавь в вопрос как подключатся скрипты на страницу

Comment: <script src = "controllers.js"></script>
<script src = "navigator.js"></script>
Ты про такое подключение ?

Comment: @Maks.Burkov, да. все в сам вопрос добавляй. какие скрипты и как. А так же что вообще используется при разработке: просто в блокноте файлы, либо какие-то IDE? может сборщики

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41061/discussion-between-grundy-and-maks-burkov).

Answer (score 0):

Решение проблемы!

Проблема - немогу передать данные вводимые в форму к функции Java Script. 
RegisterController().

Решение заключалось в не нужности использования в RegisterController "onsubmit", и прикрепление его к submit button ивенту.

"`onsubmit = "registerController()`" - этого вполне было достаточно.

Может для кого будет полезно.

```js
  function registerController(){


    var user = {

    username:document.getElementById("reg_user_name").value,
    firstname:document.getElementById("first_name").value,
    lastname:document.getElementById("last_name").value,
    userid:document.getElementById("user_id").value,
    password:document.getElementById("reg_password").value,
    email:document.getElementById("reg_email").value

    }

  registerHandler(user);

 }
```

```html
 <form id = "registrator" onsubmit = "registerController()">
  
  <label for = "reg_user_name">User name:</label>
  <input id = "reg_user_name" name = "reg_user_name" type = "text" placeholder = "user name">
  <br>
  <label for = "first_name">First name:</label>
  <input id = "first_name" name = "first_name" type = "text" placeholder = "first name">
  <br>
  <label for = "last_name">Last name:</label>
  <input id = "last_name" name = "last_name" type = "text" placeholder = "last name">
  <br>
  <label for = "user_id">Id number:</label>
  <input id = "user_id" name = "user_id" type = "number" placeholder = "id number">
  <br>
  <label for = "reg_password">Password:</label>
  <input id = "reg_password" name = "reg_password" type = "password" placeholder = "password">
  <br>
  <label for = "reg_email">Email:</label>
  <input id = "reg_email" name = "reg_email" type = "email" placeholder = "email">
  <br>
  <input id = "reg_button" name = "reg_button" type = "submit" value = "Register">


  </form>
```

Comment: стоит добавить описание в чем заключалась ошибка и что именно было сделано для того чтобы она исправилась

Comment: Предпочитайте состояниям "до/после" описание **внесённых изменений**.